# image made from dots and letters c++

Tags: c++, c++11

very basic Q as I just started with coding but I stuck at some point and have 0 ideas what to do.

I need to write code to get diamond shape made from dots and X letters, size based on a value (n) provided by the user, (3 ≤ n ≤ 80).

for example:

[image]

As I mentioned - I have almost 0 experience so all I could get is is this shape for n=6

[image]

height is ok, same as widht but unfortunately, the amount of X's and placement isn't correct :/

**my code:**

```
int h;
cerr << "Provide size of diamond: ";
cin >> h;


for (int i = 1; i <= h; i++)
{
    for (int k = 1 ; k <= h-i ; k++)
    {
        cout << ".";
    }
    for (int j = 1; j <= i ; j++)
    {
        cout << "X";
    }
    cout << endl;
```

Thank you all good people who will help mi with this one :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to avoid getting downvoted and help others to answer your question. Thanks!

Comment: If this is a homework question please tell it and maybe post the homework question as it is. Don't hesitate to read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I help to draw points. I hope you, looking on my change, are able to update your code further to achive the required picture.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= h; i++)
{
    for (int k = 1 ; k <= (h-i) / 2 ; k++)
    {
        cout << ".";
    }
    for (int j = 1; j <= i ; j++)
    {
        cout << "X";
    }
    for (int k = 1 ; k <= (h-i) / 2 ; k++)
    {
        cout << ".";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of problems you can divide the problems in different parts. Such as for n=6 the image can be divided in 4 mirror images:

```
..X
.XX
XXX
```

then,

```
X..
XX.
XXX
```

and upside down mirror of them.
You said that you can draw the first one. I think if you give some more time you will be able to print the full image too.

But, if you have problems, here's the code for that

```cpp
for (int i = 1; i <= h; i++) {
        if((h-i)%2) continue;
        for (int j = 1 ; j <= (h-i) / 2 ; j++) {
            cout << ".";
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= i ; j++) {
            cout << "X";
        }
        for (int j = 1 ; j <= (h-i) / 2 ; j++) {
            cout << ".";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    for (int i = (h/2)*2; i > 0; i--) {
        if((h-i)%2) continue;
        for (int j = 1 ; j <= (h-i) / 2 ; j++) {
            cout << ".";
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= i ; j++) {
            cout << "X";
        }
        for (int j = 1 ; j <= (h-i) / 2 ; j++) {
            cout << ".";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is tagged as a c++ question let's use `std::string` and three loops.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
void print_diamond(int n)
{
    int np = n / 2, nm = (n - 1) / 2;
    int npl = np, nml = nm;
    std::string str(n, '.');
    for (int i = 0; i < nm; i++)
    {
        str[npl++] = 'X'; str[nml--] = 'X';
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
    for (int i = nm; i <= np; i++)
    {
        str[npl] = 'X'; str[nml] = 'X';
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
    for (int i = np; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        str[npl--] = '.'; str[nml++] = '.';
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Print all diamond for a shinier world...

```
int main()
{
    for (int n = 3; n < 81; n++)
    {
        print_diamond(n);
    }
}
```